# Optional or union with forward reference in Python class, incorrectly flagged by mypy

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I defined a TreeNode class with type annotations. It accepts a TreeNode or None for the arguments in the `__init__` and in some of the class methods. The full code runs fine during testing, but when I check it with mypy it lists 4 warnings. I'm using Python 3.7.4 and mypy version 0.74.

I tried this using both the Optional["TreeNode"] and Union["TreeNode", None] keywords, but the errors persist. Note that the quotes around TreeNode are needed since it's a forward reference to a type before it is fully defined.

```
from typing import *

class TreeNode():
    def __init__(self, value,
                 parent : Optional["TreeNode"]=None,
                 left_child : Optional["TreeNode"]=None,
                 right_child : Optional["TreeNode"]=None):
        self.value = value
        self.parent = parent
        self.left_child = None
        self.right_child = None
        self.update_children(left_child, right_child)

    def get_parent(self):
        return self.parent

    def set_parent(self, other):
        self.parent = other

    def update_children(self,
                        left_child : Optional["TreeNode"] = None,
                        right_child : Optional["TreeNode"] = None):
        # update parents in children, if left or right not None.
        if left_child:
            self.left_child = left_child
            self.left_child.set_parent(self)
        if right_child:
            self.right_child = right_child
            self.right_child.set_parent(self)

    def depth(self):
        pass # full code omitted for brevity
```

Here is the mypy output:

```
tree_node.py:25: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "TreeNode", variable has type "None")
tree_node.py:26: error: "None" has no attribute "set_parent"
tree_node.py:28: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "TreeNode", variable has type "None")
tree_node.py:29: error: "None" has no attribute "set_parent"
```

I also tried the following modification to the code that mypy is complaining about, to no avail:

```
        if left_child is not None:
            self.left_child = left_child
            self.left_child.set_parent(self)
        if right_child is not None:
            self.right_child = right_child
            self.right_child.set_parent(self)
```

The question is why am I getting these errors, when I explicitly indicated that either a TreeNode or None will do, and only execute the code in question if it's not None.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with the way you're setting the left and right children inside your constructor -- specifically, these two lines:

```
self.left_child = None
self.right_child = None
```

Since these fields are being assigned `None` values, mypy ends up just conservatively inferring that the types of these fields is just exactly `None`. And `Optional[TreeNode]` is not a subtype of `None`, so the assignment in `update_children` ends up failing.

(Mypy could theoretically observe that `update_children` is being called inside the constructor and use the assignments there to infer a more accurate type for your fields, but that kind of logic would be pretty finicky to implement.)

The workaround in this case is to just explicitly give these two fields a type hint. For example, if you're using Python 3.6+, you can use variable annotations:

```
self.left_child: Optional[TreeNode] = None
self.right_child: Optional[TreeNode] = None
```

Or alternatively, if you want to support older Python versions, you can use the comment-based syntax:

```
self.left_child = None   # type: Optional[TreeNode]
self.right_child = None  # type: Optional[TreeNode]
```